# Integration of Custom Data Loader with LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to integrate Custom Data Loader with LSTM

```
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for batch_x, batch_y in dl:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(batch_x)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I have written the above code for implementing a training loop using data loader. But I am getting the error -

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-32bc0cf80d7d> in <module>
      7     for batch_x, batch_y in dl:
      8         optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 9         outputs = model(batch_x)
     10         batch_y = batch_y.to(outputs.dtype)
     11         loss = criterion(outputs, batch_y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-9-78197be44597> in forward(self, x)
      8 
      9     def forward(self, x):
---> 10         out, _ = self.lstm(x)
     11         out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])  # Taking the last timestep's output
     12         return out

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    810         self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
    811         if batch_sizes is None:
--> 812             result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers,
    813                               self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional, self.batch_first)
    814         else:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `serve` function is blocking the thread and doesn't check whether you've set the `stop_requested` event frequently enough. Once the `serve` function has started, it will keep running until it finishes, even if you set the `stop_requested` event.

Instead, we'll use Flask's built-in server and override its behavior for serving and stopping.

Here's how you can modify your `ServerThread` class:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server = None

    def run(self):
        self.server = app.run(host=self.host, port=self.port, threaded=True, use_reloader=False)

    def request_stop(self):
        if self.server:
            self.server.shutdown()
```

Please note:

1. You don't need the `running` attribute or the `is_running` method anymore. You can just check whether the `server` attribute is `None` to know if the server is running.
2. Flask's development server has a `shutdown` method that can be called to stop the server.

Now, in your `MainWindow` class, modify the `stop_button_clicked` method:

```py
def stop_button_clicked(self):
    self.stop_button.setDisabled(True)
    self.start_button.setEnabled(True)

    if self.server_thread:
        self.server_thread.request_stop()
        self.server_thread.join()
        self.server_thread = None
```

These changes should allow you to properly start and stop the Flask server from your PyQt5 GUI without the GUI freezing. Remember, whenever dealing with threads, make sure that any shared resource (like `self.server_thread`) is accessed thread-safe to avoid potential issues.